# Monstache: How do I sync new fields in MongoDB into ElasticSearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, monstache

I notice that when new fields are added into Mongo, ElasticSearch is not updated with these fields, how do I sync them over?

I am using [Monstache](https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/) to sync data into ElasticSearch. It appears it does not automatically detect new changes to fields?

Tried using [update mappings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) to add new fields, but even when I insert/update data on mongo, the new fields are not found in ES. I suspect I need to change something in monstache?

Comment: Hi,  could you explain in more details what is the issue ?

Comment: @Paulo added some details into post

Comment: Could you by any chance give us the mapping of one of your index ?